# Running Google App Engine applications in local network (GWT Development Plugin)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm developing GoogleAppEngine(GAE) applications and most of our has known that deploying apps to GAE's server take too long time.

Now, if I want to save time of development. I will run from Menu on local machine. When open Firefox/Chrome with GWT Development Plugin this link:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/QRCodeProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
Certainly, if my machine has address: 192.168.1.18 in Local network. I can make some calls from local machines to this address:
http://192.168.1.18:8888/qrcodeproject/getUserInfo

It's okay if the above Servlet does not has any GWT component. Otherwise, the link: http://192.168.1.18:8888/QRCodeProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 is not available. I can't do something, like call to RPCs.

I'm sure that I need to configure "gwt.codesvr" parameter. I don't know what does it mean, what should I place in gwt.codesvr parameter.

Can anyone show me the meaning of gwt.codesvr and GWT Developement Plugin's role

Answer (score 1):

The `gwt.codesvr` is how GWT browser plugin and dev server communicate. In dev mode GWT code is not compiled to Javascript, but is executed directly as Java bytecode on server. From the [docs on Compile & Debug](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideDevMode):

```
When an application is running in development mode, the Java Virtual Machine  
(JVM) is actually executing the application code as compiled Java bytecode, 
using GWT plumbing to connect to a browser window.
```

You can also run code in production mode (= compiled to JS, run in browser) on your dev server, but you need to [compile it first](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/compile.html#run), then invoke it without the `gwt.codesvr` in the Url.